# How to do a addition for the number which is in string format

Tags: javascript

I have got a value of 17.439702 .

I want to add 0.222 to the above value .

I was doing it this way

```
var lat = '17.439702';

 lat = parseFloat(lat)+parseFloat(0.222);

console.log(lat );
```

But the end result i am getting is

```
17.661702000000002
```

But where as i am expecting it as

```
17.661702
```

Please tell me how to resolve this

Comment: Looks like your running into a rounding error...

Comment: This is how floating-point numbers work; they are inherently imprecise and there isn't much you can do about it. If you want to display the second value, you can always round to the desired number of significant digits.

Comment: Just round the result to desired precision by `toFixed` method

Comment: that solved , thanks a lot.